# Integrating with a Dirac delta function $\delta(x-a)$ when $a$s not in the domain of integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

The delta function has the fundamental property that

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a) 
\end{align}

and, in fact,
\begin{align}
\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a) 
\end{align}
How change these formula if $a$ is not in the domain of integration?
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{a-\epsilon}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx + \int_{a+\epsilon}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx\end{align}

Also if $a$ is one of upper or lower bound?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question. Generally, we have $$\int_c^d f(x) \delta(x-a) dx = f(a)$$ whenever $c < a < d$. If $a$ is not in between $c$ and $d$, then  $$\int_c^d f(x) \delta(x-a) dx = 0.$$ Does this answer your question?

Comment: @User8128 no when a is between c and d, e.g c and d respectively are negative and positive infinity

Comment: Is that a question? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @User8128  Exactly if $x$ can get any values between $c$ and $d$ other than $a$ ( $a $ is between $c$ and $d$) what's answer of\begin{align}
\int_{c}^{d}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a) 
\end{align}

Comment: @User8128 got it?

Comment: No. I still don't know what you're asking. What does it mean to integrate from $c$ to $d$ with $c < a < d$ but also say $x$ can't equal $a$? This doesn't seem meaningful to me. When we integrate with respect to $x$, the variable $x$ isn't something we can choose or put restrictions on (we can;t just say: $x \neq a$); instead, $x$ is some dummy variable that takes values in the range of integration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39404/discussion-between-asaa-and-user8128).

Comment: I'm not too interested in continuing the discussion. It is certainly true that $$\int_{-\infty}^{a-\epsilon} f(x) \delta(x-a) dx = 0 = \int_{a+\epsilon}^\infty f(x) \delta(x-a) dx$$ which is exactly what I said in my first answer by setting $c = -\infty, d = a-\epsilon$ or $c = a+\epsilon, d = \infty$. Hence $$\int_{-\infty}^{a-\epsilon} f(x) \delta(x-a) dx + \int_{a+\epsilon}^\infty f(x) \delta(x-a) dx = 0.$$
The case when $a$ is an endpoint is a bit nebulous but the confusion only occurs when you treat $\delta(x)$ like a function; it isn't. This is the last I'll say on the matter.

Comment: Often it's OK to treat $\delta(x)$ like a function in a hand-waving manner and not worry about distribution theory too much, but if you want to get into subtle points like $a$ being one of the integration limits, you should state more explicitly what sort of setting you're operating in, e.g., what function space are you considering?

Comment: @joriki e.g coordinate

Comment: @asaa: What does that mean?

Comment: Its just clear, x!

Comment: No, it's not clear at all. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that if $\delta(t-a) = 0$ for any $t\neq a$, hence, if the integration domain does not include $a$ in the integration range, it is the same as multiplying $f(x)$ by zero, no matter how small you consider the $\epsilon$. Then the integral result is zero.

Comment: This is correct